# When is a quarter closed door the same as a quarter open door?

Tags: treasure-hunt

A half open door is always the same as a half closed door. And of course it is not a door when it is a jar.

What could be the answer?

> **Hint:** We're not talking about clopen doors. All our buildings are very simply connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it

> a two-way door / revolving door at the entrances of shopping complexes /malls

Which

> is semi-closed at one end means semi-open at the other and similarly quarter-open at one side means quarter-closed at the other

Comment: If it is a quarter closed at one end, it will be a quarter closed (three quarters open) at the other end, due to the symmetry.